# How to let the compiler to determine the API if I wrote a function with the same NAME within unistd.h

Tags: c, gcc

*myio.h*

```
extern ssize_t pwrite(int fd, void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset);
```

*myio.c*

```
ssize_t pwrite(int fd, void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset)
{
.........
}
```

**Here, compiler myio.c into an .so library.**

main.c

```
#include <myio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void main()

{
int ret;
ret = pwrite (...);
}
```

Compiler error: previous declaration of 'pwrite' was here.
My concern is, can I make it pass if I do not delete #include <unistd.h> in main.c?

Comment: You just cannot have two functions with the same name. Having a *different* name (`my_pwrite`) is one option...

Comment: If you re-implement such a function, include the system header only, in both the implementation source and the using source, don't provide an own declaration.

Comment: Do you know how to do it based on my code above?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself.
Since I want to use my own pwrite function, then I could define a different function name, like, p_write(), then use `#define pwrite p_write`

So when starting to compile, then pwrite would be replace with p_write....
Okay, this question got solved.